# Defining a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis

So I have been given the relatively easy problem of finding the plane in R3 determined by the three points $(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$, and finding the parallel subspace to this plane.

I know the definition of the plane is this: A subset $\Pi$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a plane of dimension $m$ if for some point a, $\Pi - a$ is a subspace of dimension $m$.

I think I would go about finding the plane by finding a point $a$ between the points on the x and y axis with geometry, which would be (I think) ($\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2, 0)$, and then showing that $\Pi - a$  is a subspace of dimension m. Is this correct? If so, have I found the plane? I feel like I just have shown the plane exists, which I'm not so sure shows that it is the plane that goes through those three points, as it could be the x-y plane as well. My book has no examples of this, so I'm not really sure how I go about doing this.

Also, I just have no idea how I would go about the subspace parallel to this plane. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the equation of the plane going through any given three points $\textbf{a},\textbf{b},\textbf{c}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, first take the cross product of the difference of the any two vectors, say $(\textbf{a}-\textbf{b})\times(\textbf{a}-\textbf{c}) = \textbf{n}$, this will give you a vector that is perpendicular to the plane (why?). Then you can apply this to the standard formula
$$(n_1,n_2,n_3)\cdot (x-a_1, y-a_2, z-a_3) = 0$$
and be done, or you could plug $\textbf{a} =(a_1, a_2, a_3) = (x,y,z)$  or $\textbf{b}$ or $\textbf{c}$ into the equation
$$n_1x + n_2y + n_3z = d$$ and solve for $d$.

To find the subspace that is parrallel to this plane, it would just be 
$$n_1x + n_2y + n_3z = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you. It's been a while since I've worked with vectors and the geometry of planes, this was very helpful in solidifying my understanding of vectors and planes in r3.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec p$ is a point on a plane $P$ and $\vec n$ is normal to $P$, then 
$$
P=\{\vec x\in \Bbb R^3 : \vec n\cdot(\vec x-\vec p)=0\}
$$
In our case $\vec p=(1,0,0)$ and 
$$
\vec n= \overrightarrow{e_1e_2}\times\overrightarrow{e_1e_3}=(-1,1,0)\times(-1,0,1)=(1,1,1)
$$
Hence
$$
P=\{\vec x\in\Bbb R^3:(x_1-1)+x_2+x_3=0\} 
$$
That is, $P$ is defined by the equation
$$
x+y+z=1
$$
Of course, $P$ is parallel to the linear subspace defined by the equation
$$
x+y+z=0
$$